# Vertex labels versus vertex names in VertexRenderingFunction

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, labeling

The `VertexRenderingFunction` seems to only use names, not labels. For example:

```
GraphPlot[Import["D:/dev/ProjectEuler/keylog.gv"], 
 VertexLabeling->True, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[#1, 0.08], 
   Black, Text[#2, #1]}&)]
```

The imported `gv` file here has both names and labels defined for each node. The names are always unique, but the labels are not necessarily unique.

Unfortunately, the above `GraphPlot` only shows the NAMES of the vertices, not the labels. How can I get the labels and not the names?

[image]

The vertex annotations above are names, not labels of each vertex. The `DOT` file is as follows:

```
digraph Passcode {
    0 [label="3"];
    1 [label="1"];
    2 [label="9"];
    3 [label="6"];
    4 [label="8"];
    5 [label="0"];
    6 [label="2"];
    7 [label="7"];
    0 -> 1;
    0 -> 2;
    0 -> 3;
    0 -> 4;
    1 -> 4;
    1 -> 6;
    1 -> 5;
    1 -> 3;
    1 -> 2;
    2 -> 5;
    3 -> 4;
    3 -> 2;
    3 -> 6;
    3 -> 5;
    4 -> 5;
    4 -> 2;
    6 -> 2;
    6 -> 5;
    6 -> 4;
    7 -> 3;
    7 -> 1;
    7 -> 6;
    7 -> 0;
    7 -> 2;
}
```

Comment: If you can provide actual data files, it will be much helpful to diagnose..

Comment: @halmir I pasted the contents into the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could import it first and modify options:

```
g = Import["D:/dev/ProjectEuler/keylog.gv"];

SetProperty[g, {EdgeStyle -> Black, VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[#1, 0.08]} &),
 VertexLabels -> (#1 -> Placed[#2, Center]) & @@@ (VertexLabels /. 
 Options[g, VertexLabels]), GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The vertices in the imported graph object `g0` are already labeled with the *labels*, not the *names*.

```
g0 = Import["D:/dev/ProjectEuler/keylog.gv"]
```

[image]

So we are left with the task of modifying the layout and styles of vertices and edges which can be done using `SetProperty`.

```
SetProperty[g0, {VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> Large, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> 20, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", 
  VertexLabels -> (# -> Placed[#2, Center] & @@@ (VertexLabels /. Options[g0]))}]
```

[image]

***Import* with *Graph* options:**

A convenient feature of `Import` for `DOT` files is that

> - When importing from *DOT*, all options supported by *Graph* can be given.  ([DOT >> Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/DOT.html))

So, we can set the `Graph` options during importing:

```
g1 = Import["D:/dev/ProjectEuler/keylog.gv", 
  VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> Large, VertexLabelStyle -> 20, 
  GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

This just leaves the centering of vertex labels for which we need `SetProperty`:

```
SetProperty[g1, 
  VertexLabels -> (# -> Placed[#2, Center] & @@@ (VertexLabels /. Options[g1]))]
```

[image]

**Using *GraphPlot***

If you have to use `GraphPlot` you can use the `VertexLabels` of the imported `Graph` object to construct a replacement rule to be used in the `VertexRenderingFunction`:

```
vreplace = (VertexLabels /. Options[g0]) /. Rule[x_, y_] :> Rule[1 + ToExpression[x], y];
```

We can use `vreplace` to post-process the `GraphPlot` output in OP:

```
GraphPlot[g0, VertexLabeling -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[#1, 0.08],
       Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)] /. Text[v_, p_] :> Text[v /. vreplace, p]
```

[image]

Or,  use it inside `VertexRenderingFunction`:

```
GraphPlot[g0, VertexLabeling -> All, PlotStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 400, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[#1, 0.08], 
   Black, Text[#2 /. vreplace, #1]} &)]
```

[image]

Or, add `Tooltip`s showing both the name and the label of a vertex using

```
VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[#1, 0.08], 
    Black, Text[Tooltip[#2 /. vreplace, 
      Grid[{{"name", #2}, {"label", #2 /. vreplace}}, Dividers -> All]], #1]} &)
```

[image]

**Note:** When `g` is a `Graph` object, `GraphPlot[g]` takes `Range @ VertexCount[g]`, that is, the list of vertex indices, as the vertex list, not the vertex names. A simpler example:

```
exmpl = Graph[{10 -> "A", "A" -> 30, 30 -> 10}, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> 20, VertexStyle -> White, 
   VertexSize -> Medium, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{exmpl, GraphPlot[exmpl, VertexLabeling -> True, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]